# Erro Função Javascript

Tags: javascript

alguem poderia me dizer o que estou errando nessa função do js?

```
        alert("Insira o numero a ser pesquisado");
        var num = prompt("Insira um numero: ");

        var array = [2,23,4,56,7];

        function pesquisa(array[], num){
            var achou = false;

            for(var i=0; i < array.length-1;i++){
                if(array[i] == num)
                {
                    achou = true;
                }
            }
             return achou;
        }

        if(pesquisa(array,num) == true)
        {
            alert("o elemento procurado está dentro do array");
        }
        else
        {
            alert("O elemento não está no array");
        }
```

Comment: Cuidado com o `i < array.length-1`, o `<` já corrige o limite superior para o último elemento. E além disso não existe a notação `array[]` no javascript, troque para `array` apenas.

Comment: Não entendo o porque da pergunta do rapaz ter sido negativada....

Comment: @MarceloBonifazio Não fui o *downvoter*, mas creio que a razão do voto contra é porque costuma-se desencorajar perguntas do tipo "achem o erro aí pra mim" sem nenhuma indicação de que algo foi tentado (tipo, em que linha esta o erro? deu mensagem de erro ou só o resultado que está errado? etc).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

na linha:

```
function pesquisa(array[], num){
```

modifique para:

```
function pesquisa(array, num) {
```

e tudo funcionará como esperado

Comment: "tudo funcionará como esperado" nem tudo, vide [o comentário do @Wakim...](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/31959/erro-fun%c3%a7%c3%a3o-javascript#comment60238_31959) Isso resolve o erro de sintaxe, mas não o de semântica (se o elemento sendo buscado for o último, o código do AP não o encontrará).

Comment: sim toda a razão... e pelo que percebo a minha resposta foi posterior ... portanto o meu voto para o @Wakin